I cant seem to get lightboxes right in css
long time lurker and im trying to teach myself front end. Im working through a book and i cant get the lightbox right. I want to make a sign in box pop up and dim the rest of the screen. I cant seem to style the div i made for the background and im doing it right out of the book. here is the code
<div class="lightbox">
            <div class="lightbox_background""> </div>
            <div class="lightbox_content">content</div>
        </div>

div.lightbox_background{
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: #0000000;
    opacity: 0.8;
    border: 20px groove red;
}

im not getting any styling at all, just the content at the bottom of the page.
I have used multiple books and articals on the concept of lightboxes and css in general

Probably not an issue but you have an extra " character in your lightbox_background div

At a guess, you're missing position: absolute or similar. You can't really use top and left without it

It works for me, so did you put 
i do have them linked, and i had made the position absolute. the extra space was because i thought perhaps there needed to be content in the tag. so this should work is what you think?

It would "work" as in that it renders as is to be expected, once position: absolute gets added, and the error of the double quote character in your currently shown HTML is fixed - https://jsfiddle.net/dhjwrkgs/ That the element gets wider and higher than the viewport, is of course because you added a 20px border, to a width and height that were already covering all the available space. Go look into the box model, and the box-sizing property. Or don't specify width and height to begin with here, and specify the "opposite" corners as well (bottom, and right.)
